# No Solarized Light in GVim (GTK3)

Tags: gvim, colorscheme

I manually installed the [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) colour scheme from the Vim-only [repository](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) and adjusted my ~/.vimrc as indicated in the documentation, including using `set background=dark`.

GVim 7.4 (GTK3) under Kubuntu 16.04 correctly displays the dark solarized theme. However, changing the configuration to `set background=light` as detailed in the documentation results in the same dark color scheme after calling `colourscheme solarized` again or after restarting Vim with the new configuation. How do I use the light theme in GVim?

PS: I installed G/Vim (GTK3) 8.0 from the git source. It, too, does not display the light theme.

Comment: Where did you place the solarized color scheme file?

Comment: In `~/.vim/colors` as instructed in the manual instructions here: https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized -- the dark theme works; the light theme does not.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me (GVim 7.4, Ubuntu 16.04.2):

~/.vimrc

```
set background=dark
set t_Co=16              " fix for bg being too bright
colorscheme solarized

" gvim specific settings here                       
if has('gui_running')
    set background=light
    set guioptions-=T    " no toolbar
    set linespace=5      " to show underscores not as space
endif
```

Comment: Have you tested that? I would have thought (another) `colorscheme` would be required after setting the light background? Either way, this is unrelated to my question, as I have followed the instructions for the light theme, but it does not appear.

Comment: I copied these settings directly from my vimrc. So yes it's tested and works (at least on my system).

Comment: @SabreWolfy: You don't generally need to call `:colorscheme` after setting the background. As `:help 'background'` states: "When a color scheme is loaded (the "g:colors_name" variable is set) setting 'background' will cause the color scheme to be reloaded.  If the color scheme adjusts to the value of 'background' this will work."